# Expanding sys.path via __init__.py

Tags: python

There're a lot of threads on importing modules from sibling directories, and majority recommends to either simply add **init**.py to source tree, or modify sys.path from inside those init files.

Suppose I have following project structure:

```
project_root/
    __init__.py
    wrappers/
        __init__.py
        wrapper1.py
        wrapper2.py
    samples/
        __init__.py
        sample1.py
        sample2.py
```

All **init**.py files contain code which inserts absolute path to project_root/ directory into the sys.path. I get "No module names x", no matter how I'm trying to import wrapperX modules into sampleX. And when I try to print sys.path from sampleX, it appears that it does not contain path to project_root.

So how do I use **init**.py correctly to set up project environment variables?

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening here. You're not expecting project_root/__init__.py to insert project_root into your sys.path, I hope. Since that would be a chicken-and-egg type problem.

Comment: I did'n mention it, but EACH init.py checks if project_root path is already inserted into sys.path and inserts it if it's not. So there's no egg-chicken problem. Anyway, why __init__.py does not have any affect? When I execute sampleX script, sys.path contains only current script directory + some standard lib paths. How can I fix it?

Comment: But if project_root isn't already inserted,  none of your \_\_init\_\_'s will ever be found. Hence project_root will never be inserted by them. Right?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbee in python, so I might have made something wrong. What I'm trying to do is to directly execute script from samples folder. That's why I'm adding project_root path manually. When I create script inside root_directory, I can import everything I need. But when I create and run script in samples directory and try to import something from it's siblings directories, I get those problems I mentioned.

So basically I want to have behaviour similar to what we have in c++, when you can specify include directory list first and then include pretty much everything from anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not run `sampleX.py` directly, execute as module instead:

```
# (in project root directory)
python -m samples.sample1
```

This way you do not need to fiddle with `sys.path` at all (which is generally discouraged). It also makes it much easier to use the samples/ package as a library later on.

Oh, and **init**.py is not run because it only gets run/imported (which is more or less the same thing) if you import the samples package, not if you run an individual file as script.

Comment: Thans, that's what I was looking for!